# Why is h1's "padding: 2em" is equal to 64px? I think it should be 16px*2

Tags: html, css

Why is my h1's `padding: 2em` equal to 64px? I think it should be `16px` * 2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 2em;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The result:

[image: result]

Comment: _Why_ do you think it should be `16px*2`? You have not explicitly specified any font sizes here, so the browser stylesheet will apply. And most likely, in there the font-size for h1 is set to 2em, and the font-size for the root element is usually set to 16px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `em` unit refers to the font-size of the current element, so if for your `h1` `font-size` is set to 32px (in your case obviously by the browser default settings), `2em` will be 32x2 = 64px.

(You are obviously mixing it up with the `rem` unit, which refers to the "root"  font-size.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know what the problem is. For the font size attribute, EM is based on the font size of the parent element. However, when calculating the box model, EM is the font size calculated based on the element itself.

Comment: I always thought EM was calculated based on the font size of the parent element...